# Modify NavigationBar on route change

Tags: javascript, ios, navigation, react-native

I can't find any documentation for how this should be done with the `<Navigator/>` component... Basically, when one of my scenes loads, I want to be able to, say, pass a `route.navBarColor` to my navigator that will automatically change the background color of the bar.

I have tried pushing a route with `{navBarColor: 'red'}`, etc... to `renderScene()`, but this does not work because `renderScene()` doesn't seem to have a reference to `this`, and when I `bind(this)` it, the entire scene does not render, and throws a Stack Overflow error.

Basically, I want to do something like this:

`navigator.push({name: 'TestScene', navBarColor: 'transparent'})`

Which then goes to

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if(route.navBarColor) {
       this.setState({navBarColor: navBarColor});
    } ... etc.
}
```

Where `this.state.navBarColor` is used to set the `backgroundColor` prop of the `navigationBar`.

Is this possible with the `Navigator` component? I see that it appears to be with `NavigatorIOS`, so I don't understand why it wouldn't be here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Navigator` component has no display of its own, it only manages the scene transitions and routing, so asking how to do this "with Navigator" is not right.  This is contrasted with `NavigatorIOS` which dictates the display as well.

Your question mentions "NavigationBar", is that [React Native Navbar](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar)?

If yes, somewhere in the renderScene() function there will be a reference to the  component, you simply need to pass it the appropriate navBarColor prop.

```
<NavigationBar statusBar={{ tintColor: route.navBarColor }} />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I'm using the `<Navigator.NavigationBar/>` component built into React Native (with a route mapper). As far as you're aware, then, there's no way to change that color? Thanks.